# How to run the jsp file in wampserver?

Tags: wamp

I have an index.jsp file and uploaded it into the www folder of WAMP (apache). When I try to run it via localhost, it only displays the code. Can you please explain me how to run the index.jsp file on my WAMP server?

Answer (score 1):

JSP-files are Java Server Pages files. You need servlet container to run them (e.g. tomcat).

Nowadays it is quite uncommon to write web application just using jsp. More common way is that jsp is used as view technology with some application framework. So I'd make sure the jsp-file you have is a complete application instead of some page in some bigger application.

Note that this very highly simplified answer, more from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages).

Comment: Well, then the answer is you can't (at least in pure meaning of wamp). Probably the most used way to view jsp in apache is to install tomcat and use mod_proxy or mod_jk2 in apache. More about these apache modules: http://rimuhosting.com/mod_jk2_and_mod_proxy_ajp.jsp